# Displaying frames in TKinter without classes

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently writing a library system and, in order to better understand how to change between frames, have so far have written code for a screen the user is met with when they first use the program as shown below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

window = tk.Tk()  # creates a window

width = 474  # sets the width and height of the screen
height = 266

screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()  # finds the width of the user's screen
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
center_x = int(screen_width / 2 - width / 2)
center_y = int(screen_height / 2 - height / 2)
window.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')  # sets the width, height, and positioning of the window

window.title("Library System")  # sets title of window
window.resizable(False, False)  # Prevents the window being resized by both the x and y coordinates

welcome = tk.Frame(width=200, height=200, background="light cyan")
ChangeInfo = tk.Frame(window, width=400, height=200)

ChangeInfo.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)


def WelcomeScreen():

    greeting = tk.Label(welcome, text="Welcome", font=("comic sans", 15), bg ='light cyan')  # creates a lable with text
    greeting.pack()

    explaination = tk.Label(welcome, text="This is your first time using this program so please click the button below to "
                                         "enter in \n the username "
                                         "and password you will be using to log into the system in the future"
                                         "", font=("comic_sans", 9), bg="light cyan")
    explaination.place(x = (width)/2, y= 50, anchor='center')

    login_button = tk.Button(welcome, text="Set username and password", height=3, width=22,
                             font=("comic_sans", 10), bg = "turquoise")
    login_button.place(x= width / 2, y= height / 2, anchor='center')


    window.mainloop()

WelcomeScreen()
```

The only thing that is displayed at the moment is the window and its title. How do I display the frame instead of only the window?

Comment: You need to call `welcome.pack(...)` instead of `ChangeInfo.pack(...)` in order to show the welcome frame first.

Comment: @acw1668 Don't hesitate to put your solution into an answer.  This will give you credit for looking at the problem, and let others that the question has been answered.  For questioner, make sure you accept the answer so they get credit  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the welcome frame initially, you need to call `welcome.pack(...)` instead of `ChangeInfo.pack(...)`.